# Compiling errors when compiling "MATRIX Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)"

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation

```
git clone https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal.git

cd matrix-creator-hal
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

when i cmake, i get this error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- * * * A D M O B I L I Z E * * *
-- Admobilize: Please treat warnings as errors. Use: -DADM_FATAL_WARNINGS=ON
-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
-- * * * A D M O B I L I Z E * * *
-- Admobilize: Please treat warnings as errors. Use: -DADM_FATAL_WARNINGS=ON
-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- * * * A D M O B I L I Z E * * *
-- Admobilize: Please treat warnings as errors. Use: -DADM_FATAL_WARNINGS=ON
-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FFTW_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "direction_of_arrival_demo" in directory /home/pi/Test/matrix-creator-hal/build/matrix-creator-hal/demos
    linked by target "matrix_creator_hal" in directory /home/pi/Test/matrix-creator-hal/build/matrix-creator-hal/cpp/driver

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/Test/matrix-creator-hal/build/matrix-creator-hal/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you followed the install instructions for dependencies at https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the FFTW library as specified in the instructions.

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev
```

Start again after that.